# Lost headers when using UnZipResultSplitter

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the Spring Integration Zip extension and it appears that I'm losing headers I've added upstream in the flow. I'm guessing that they are being lost in `UnZipResultSplitter.splitUnzippedMap()` as I don't see anything that explicitly copies them over.

I seem to recall that this is not unusual with splitters but I can't determine what strategy one should use in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep!

It looks like a bug.

The `splitter` contract is like this:

```
if (item instanceof Message) {
    builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage((Message<?>) item);
}
else {
    builder = this.getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(item);
    builder.copyHeaders(headers);
}
```

So, if those splitted items are messages already, like in case of our `UnZipResultSplitter`, we just use message as is without copying headers from upstream.

Please, raise a JIRA ticket (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT) on the matter.

Meanwhile let's consider some workaround:

```
public class MyUnZipResultSplitter {

    public List<Message<Object>> splitUnzipped(Message<Map<String, Object>> unzippedEntries) {

        final List<Message<Object>> messages = new ArrayList<Message<Object>>(unzippedEntries.size());

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : unzippedEntries.getPayload().entrySet()) {
            final String path = FilenameUtils.getPath(entry.getKey());
            final String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(entry.getKey());
            final Message<Object> splitMessage =  MessageBuilder.withPayload(entry.getValue())
                .setHeader(FileHeaders.FILENAME, filename)
                .setHeader(ZipHeaders.ZIP_ENTRY_PATH, path)
                .copyHeaders(unzippedEntries/getHeaders())
                .build();
            messages.add(splitMessage);
        }
        return messages;
    }

}
```